# Different content, one database

Tags: multi-sites

Is it possible to have a multi-site installation, where I have different content for each site, but using a single database?

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is possible. Use the [Domain module](https://www.drupal.org/project/domain). But if the sites will not share any data, no special modules are needed. Set a unique “Table name prefix” when installing Drupal on each site instance.

Comment: Actually I am interested in creating a jobboard for many countries .i.e one jobboard for each country.Each jobboard will have different content(i.e. different jobs).Which method should I use for such a multisite project?Thanks

Comment: We cannot give opinion-based answers here.

Comment: @Dion This answer already answers the content part. The fact content is collected in job boards doesn't change the answer.

Comment: @apaderno That makes sense,thanks for the help.